PostgreSQL many rows vs many columns
I was told that it's better to have many rows of data instead of many columns in DB. I need a DB for transactional application, and intend to use PostgreSQL DB. As far as I understand I have these two options:
Option 1:
id | user_id | key     | value
-----------------------------------
1  | 1       | name    | jon
2  | 1       | surname | snow
3  | 1       | address | winterfell
4  | 2       | name    | daenerys
5  | 2       | surname | targaryen
6  | 2       | address | essos

Option 2:
id | name     | surname   | address
--------------------------------------
1  | jon      | snow      | winterfell
2  | daenerys | targaryen | essos

Can anyone advise what is the correct way for PostgreSQL DBs?

What you are saying is that ...where key = 'name' and value = 'some_name' and key = 'address' and value = 'some_address' is more efficient then ... where name = 'some_name' and address = 'some_address'. I'm not buying it. If you want to test it though build a large dataset and use both methods. Run queries with EXPLAIN ANALYZE and see for your self.

This is a statement taken out of context. When people say many columns are bad, they are talking 50-100 columns, not 3.

Normalization vs key-value store. And forget data integrity with a key value store, one of the benefits of a relational database. Your claim that less columns are faster, is something you have to test for yourself on your database. But it's unlikely.

Don't concentrate on the column count but rather on what is the correct way for transaction type applications?

The first table design is a standard unnormalized key value store.  Adding an additional key/value pair requires only adding a new record, which is a relatively cheap and simple operation.  Accessing certain values can be achieved via an aggregation query with pivoting:
SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE "key" = name) AS name,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE "key" = surname) AS surname
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id;

The second table design can achieve the same as above using a much simpler query:
SELECT user_id, name, surname
FROM table2;

But the drawback here is that the table structure is rigid and fixed.  If you do need to frequently add or remove user attributes, it requires an intrusive ALTER statement to the entire table, to add or remove columns.
The option you choose depends on your data model.  For a known/fixed set of user attributes, the second options looks better.  If user attributes are unknown and you require more flexibility, the first option might be a better choice.

Maybe adding a details JOSNB column to option 2 for non-key attributes that might appear later during the application lifetime is a reasonable compromise?

@Stefanov.sm Yes, using JSON is an alternative to option 2...but the OP did not mention it.

If you know roughly what the attributes would be, then you should go with option 2. It'll allow you to define better indexes on your table, thus improving read performance. With option 1, it's likely you'll have a small number of distinct values in the key column, so even index scans will be slow.
The only reason I'd use option 1 is if I either have no idea what the attributes will be and/or the number of attributes is huge (e.g. say 100 attributes). Even then, I'd prefer to model this data as a one-to-many relationship using multiple tables.
